# Открытие и закрытие нового окна в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В общем ошибка такая. Вначале открываю окно с помощью следующей команды:

```
    public void OnNewSiteClick(object p)
    {
        ns = new NewSite();
        ns.Show();
    }
```

Забиндил так:

```
  <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Create new password" 
           Height="50" Margin="10" Command="{Binding Path=NewSiteClick}"/>
```

Закрываю с помощью данной команды

```
    public void OnNewSiteClick(object p)
    {
        mainWindnowVM = new MainWindnowVM();
        mainWindnowVM.Sites.Add(new SiteConfig(SiteName, Password, Uri));

        mainWindnowVM.ns.Close();
    }
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку закрытия происходит такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также пробовал сразу создавать объект `NewSite` из конструктора, убрав инициализацию из `OnNewSiteClick()`

```
public MainWindnowVM()
    {
        _sites = new ObservableCollection<SiteConfig>()
        {
            new SiteConfig("Google", "432425425623", new Uri("http://professorweb.ru")),
            new SiteConfig("Yandex", "423524532", new Uri("http://professorweb.ru"))
        };

        HyperlinkClick = new LambdaCommand(OnHyperlinkClick, CanHyperlinkClick);
        NewSiteClick = new LambdaCommand(OnNewSiteClick, CanNewSiteClick);
        ns = new NewSite();
    }
```

Но так ловлю переполнение стека в конструкторе класса окна `NewSite`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кадр стека:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `MainWindnowVM` - это основная VM? Если да, то `mainWindnowVM = new MainWindnowVM();` - подумайте хорошенько, что тут происходит. Вот что такое `new`? Новое, да? Так если это новый объект `MainWindowVM`, то в нем есть то, что было инициализировано ранее, с другим объектом? Вот у вас есть две одинаковые корзинки, в одну вы положили яблоко, в другой это яблоко появится? Нет. Почему тут вдруг должно? Передавайте ссылку на эту VM в ту, где нужно к ней обращаться, без создания нового экземпляра. И да, подобное открытие окон - нарушение MVVM, ибо вы явно руководите View из ViewModel слоя.

Comment: Понял ошибку, но можете подсказать тогда каким образом передавать ссылку на основную `VM` в команду и закрывать окно. Да, я понимаю  что подобное открытие окон это нарушение MVVM, но я сейчас просто хотел попробовать это сделать, видел что окрытавют окна с помощью сторонего сервиса связанного с `View`, чтобы не нарушать принцип MVVM, но щас хочу просто разобраться почему ловлю здесь переполнение стека.

Comment: Вы дошли до MVVM и прочих этих приблуд, но не знаете как из класса в класс передать ссылку?) Вот у вас есть `class SomeClass`, вам надо в него передать некое значение, как поступите? Наверно через конструктор, верно? То есть `new MyClass(1)`, или метод `myClass.Method(1)`, или может даже свойство `myClass.Property = 1`. Вот собственно передача объекта класса ни чем не отличается от передачи значения, делаете конструктор и вперед.

Comment: Ну а "переполнение" - в указанном коде его нет, скорей всего у вас в XAML или где-то еще есть инициализация `NewSite`, который инициализирует `MainWindnowVM`, а тот инициализирует `NewSite`, ну и так по кругу. Изучайте XAML (`<...DataContext>...</...DataContext>` - это инициализация, аналог `new()` через XAML), изучайте свой код, пользуйтесь отладкой в конце концов, где вы пошагово можете пройтись и посмотреть как и что работает.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ, оказалось дело в `DataContext`, на счет передачи через конструктор конечно знал, но думал что есть другие варианты.

Comment: `DataContext` в XAML - тоже нарушение MVVM)

Comment: Хах и за это тоже благодарю)